# Conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(A\mid A+B+C = 3)$ question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $A,B, C$ are independent random variables with same exponential distribution.
Find $\mathbb{E}(A\mid A+B+C = 3)$

Can I write it so: $\mathbb{E}(A\mid A+B+C = 3) = \mathbb{E}(B\mid A+B+C = 3) = \mathbb{E}(C\mid A+B+C = 3)$

and the solution is $\mathbb{E}(A\mid A+B+C = 3) = \frac{1}{3}\mathbb{E}(A+B+C\mid A+B+C = 3)=1$

Comment: Correct. Symmetry and linearity of expectation are powerful!